# why is chmod -rwx not removing all the permissions on my private key file, the answers here that I have seen did not help me?

Tags: permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux, chmod

```
 chmod -rwx prac1
abayomi@AbayomiUsman:~/.ssh$ ll | grep prac1
-r-xr-xr-x 1 abayomi abayomi 2655 Feb 18 15:55 prac1*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 abayomi abayomi  574 Feb 18 15:55 prac1.pub*

abayomi@AbayomiUsman:~/.ssh$ chmod a-rwx prac1
abayomi@AbayomiUsman:~/.ssh$ ll | grep prac1
-r-xr-xr-x 1 abayomi abayomi 2655 Feb 18 15:55 prac1*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 abayomi abayomi  574 Feb 18 15:55 prac1.pub*

abayomi@AbayomiUsman:~/.ssh$ chmod -rwx prac1
abayomi@AbayomiUsman:~/.ssh$ chmod -rwx prac1
abayomi@AbayomiUsman:~/.ssh$ sudo chmod -rwx prac1
[sudo] password for abayomi:
abayomi@AbayomiUsman:~/.ssh$ ll | grep prac1
-r-xr-xr-x 1 abayomi abayomi 2655 Feb 18 15:55 prac1*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 abayomi abayomi  574 Feb 18 15:55 prac1.pub*
abayomi@AbayomiUsman:~/.ssh$
```

result for findmnt -T .

```
 findmnt -T .
TARGET SOURCE FSTYPE OPTIONS
/mnt/c C:\    drvfs  rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,case=off
```

i further went to do more things like

```
ssh -i prac1 root@143.198.6.191
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0777 for 'prac1' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "prac1": bad permissions
root@143.198.6.191: Permission denied (publickey).
abayomi@AbayomiUsman:~/.ssh$ ll | grep prac1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 abayomi abayomi 2655 Feb 18 15:55 prac1*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 abayomi abayomi  574 Feb 18 15:55 prac1.pub*
abayomi@AbayomiUsman:~/.ssh$ chmod -rwx prac1
chmod: prac1: new permissions are ----w--w-, not ---------
abayomi@AbayomiUsman:~/.ssh$ chmod a-rwx prac1
abayomi@AbayomiUsman:~/.ssh$ ll | grep prac1
-r-xr-xr-x 1 abayomi abayomi 2655 Feb 18 15:55 prac1*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 abayomi abayomi  574 Feb 18 15:55 prac1.pub*
abayomi@AbayomiUsman:~/.ssh$
```

but it still won't delete the permissions completely, i don't know why please help

This is the result after trying the solution provided on the referenced article

```
    chmod -rwx prac1
chmod: prac1: new permissions are ----w--w-, not ---------
abayomi@AbayomiUsman:~/.ssh$ chmod a-rwx prac1
abayomi@AbayomiUsman:~/.ssh$ ll | grep prac1
-r-xr-xr-x 1 abayomi abayomi 2655 Feb 18 15:55 prac1*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 abayomi abayomi  574 Feb 18 15:55 prac1.pub*
```

It still wouldn't delete all the permissions

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the output of `findmnt -T .` run from the same (`.ssh`) directory please?

Comment: Indeed you are thinking a fat32 partition, never gave that one a thought until now...

Comment: @steeldriver i just did that you should see it now thank you

Comment: @muru no it doesn't i have tried it i'll post the result now all the permissions were not deleted i don't know why

Comment: I guess ubuntu decided to represent it like that cause they're the same here is the result trying to act on the *  chmod -rwx prac1*
chmod: prac1.pub: new permissions are ----w--w-, not ---------
abayomi@AbayomiUsman:~/.ssh$ ll | grep prac1*
abayomi@AbayomiUsman:~/.ssh$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FSTYPE is drvfs so this looks like it is WSL on Windows.

Try changing the mount options to include fmask=111 to remove the eXecute bit.

Take a look under Mount Options here:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/chmod-chown-wsl-improvements/

Comment: Thank you so much Chris Taylor i'm really grateful it has worked i have been able to log into my server thank you so much GOD bless you i only needed to set that fmask option to 111 and all the x permissions went off and i was able to give only me access to the file thank you so much it has worked

Comment: Thank you so much it woked i've been able to delete rwx from all other users leaving only me using chmod 700 after i set the mount option fmask to 111. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AbayomiUsman if this answer solved your issue, please consider accepting it

Comment: @steeldriver I have already or is there way to indicate that on this platform?

Comment: @AbayomiUsman see [How do I “accept” an answer?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Set the permissions you want directly and be done with it.

```
zeus@zeus-H370M:~/test$ ls -l
total 257548
-rw-r--r-- 1 zeus zeus     31758 May  4  2020 1588603424397.JPEG
-rw-r--r-- 1 zeus zeus    274601 Mar 15  2020 Screen_Shot.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 zeus zeus 263407719 Feb  2 00:36 Test.mkv
-rw-r--r-- 1 zeus zeus         4 Feb 18 11:19 untitled.txt
zeus@zeus-H370M:~/test$ chmod 0600 *
zeus@zeus-H370M:~/test$ ls -l
total 257548
-rw------- 1 zeus zeus     31758 May  4  2020 1588603424397.JPEG
-rw------- 1 zeus zeus    274601 Mar 15  2020 Screen_Shot.png
-rw------- 1 zeus zeus 263407719 Feb  2 00:36 Test.mkv
-rw------- 1 zeus zeus         4 Feb 18 11:19 untitled.txt
```

Comment: it did not work the write and execute permissions refuse to delete